# Why the title in this scroll panel is not visible?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a scroll panel but I cann't put the visible title in it:

```
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()
                   .setId('panel')
                   .setTitle("This is my Title");                  
    panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', arrayList.length));
    // add 1 checkbox + 1 hidden field per item 
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){
      var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(arrayList[i][0]);
      panel.add(checkbox);
    }
    var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
    panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));  
   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 300).setTitle("My second try to put a title");
   scroll.add(panel);
   app.add(scroll);
    mydoc.show(app);
```

What is going wrong with my titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are making a confusion on what 'title' means in UiApp... They are actually small popups that appear when your mouse hovers the widget, see illustration below.
[image]

If you intend to get a title shown in your Ui (in the common sense of 'title') use `Label` or `HTML` widgets.

One exception though since you are using uiApp in a spreadsheet or a document, the title of the app itself is shown as a title. See example below :

```
 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('app title');
```

[image]

Comment: I'm waiting for your book! I read 4 or 5 GAS answers from you today!

Comment: Thanks !  [published](http://www.packtpub.com/google-apps-script-for-beginners/book) yesterday ;)

Comment: Just buy your book on amazon! In one or two months it arrives in my country (Brazil). Serge, but I got this error `TypeError: Cannot find function setLabel in object ScrollPanel`. How to put a label in it?

Answer (score 0):

The label must be putted in `UiApp` object, this way:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var label = app.createLabel("This is my label, ie, the user visible title").setStyleAttribute("fontSize", 18);
app.add(label);
```